# How can I send data through URL without using variables?

Tags: php, hyperlink

We usually send data to another page using variables in URL. An example is `http://www.somelink.com?var1=data1&var2=data2`. And we receive the data using `$_GET['var1']` and `$_GET['var2']`.

How can I achieve this in using standard slash format. What I need is similar to `http://www.somelink.com/var1-data1-var2-data2`

I got this idea on seeing this link: `http://freelivebox.eu/matchid-130102021307-link-5-watch-Youzhny---Davydenko-(ATP-Doha).html`

Comment: Are you running on apache?

Comment: Read up on [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)

Comment: If you haven't explored this option yet, you may be able to use session variables or cookies to achieve your goal.  But if you need to have your URL displaying your variables then URL Rewriting would be what you need to look into.

Comment: @Guy Ya, Apache and pages are PHP pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with .htaccess file like below

```
RewriteRule ^var1-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$-var2-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$  youpage.php?var1=$1&var2=$2;
```

or you can can split it regular expression-

Answer (score 2):

The best way I could think of is by using some sort of Regular Expression matching that all gets routed through a single PHP routing file.

Or by using Apache's rewrite capabilities.